# SQLAlchemy adds "=1" to the end of subqueries for no reason

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run a subquery and then an update based on matching to that subquery. Everything would work fine with the output SQL, except SQLAlchemy adds "=1" to the end of my subquery seemingly for no reason, which makes the update hit 0 rows. Here's the code:

```
to_update = session.query(DSI.id)\
    .join(TB)\
    .join(TBC)\
    .join(TBCTD)\
    .filter(func.DATE(TBCTD.dt)
            == func.subdate(func.current_date(), 2))\
    .filter(DSI.score > 110)\
    .group_by(func.DATE(TBCTD.dt),
              DSI.name, DSI.a_id)\
    .having(func.sum(
        TBCTD.num_things
        > 100)).subquery()
session.query(DSI).filter(DSI.id == to_update.c.id)\
   .update({"some_num": DSI.some_num*.98})
```

The MYSQL spit out from this looks like:

```
UPDATE dsis, (SELECT dsis.id AS id
FROM dsis 
INNER JOIN tbs ON tbs.id = dsis.a_id 
INNER JOIN tbcs ON tbs.id = tbcs.a_id 
INNER JOIN tbctds ON tbcs.id = tbctds.tbcs_id
WHERE DATE(tbctds.dt) = subdate(CURRENT_DATE, %s) 
AND dsis.score > %s 
GROUP BY DATE(tbctds.dt), dsis.name, dsis.a_id
HAVING sum(tbctds.num_things > %s) = 1) 
AS anon_1 
SET dsis.some_num=(dsis.some_num * %s) 
WHERE dsis.id = anon_1.id
2015-02-20 21:11:53,164 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (2, 110, 100, 0.98)
```

As you can see, an extra "= 1" is tacked on to the end of the subquery for absolutely no reason, and I have no idea. I've tried rewriting the statement a few ways and always wind up with the same problem.

Comment: I'm wondering what `func.sum(TBCTD.num_things > 100)` should do. Did you misplace a closing `)`?

Comment: It should SUM TBCTD.num_things based on the group by... You can see correct behavior in the output SQL. Everything in the output SQL is correct except the added "= 1".

Comment: @Eli, so it should be `func.sum(TBCTD.num_things) > 100`?

Comment: Yup. That did it. Stupid me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were supposed to write

```
having(func.sum(TBCTD.num_things) > 100)
```

which tests that the `sum()` is greater than 100. Instead of that you wrote

```
having(func.sum(TBCTD.num_things > 100))
```

which would sum booleans (which in turn are `TINYINT(1)`.

Fhe funny thing is that true as a integer is -1, and false is 0; so you would end with a non-positive integer); SQLAlchemy knows it needs a boolean for `having`, so it tries to test truthness of it by comparing it to `1`; after all a `TINYINT(1)` having value of `-1` will equal `1` in MySQL because the `1` as a constant is coerced to the range of `TINYINT(1)`.

However in your case the `HAVING` clause can *never* be true since the result is not a boolean, and also non-positive.